# Is it possible to bring a sparkline from microsoft excel into microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Pretty much trying to show the small sparkline from an excel report in a table within a microsoft word document. The only guidance that I have found so far is to convert each individual sparkline into an image. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can click Insert > Table > Excel Spreadsheet. Create a table with the small sparkline .Or you can directly copy and paste the table in the excel report into the blank Excel Spreadsheet. If you just want to insert the small sparkline, it won't work if you copy and paste the sparkline only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is another way that worked real well for me, but you might need an adobe acrobat editor.

First you set up your spreadsheet in the print preview the way you want it to look.

Second you save the excel file as a pdf.

Next you export the pdf to a word document.

The end result is a word document with your sparklines perfectly transferred.  One problem I have yet to resolve with this, is that result looks perfect, but it doesn't move around the document cleanly